# Why linear polarizing film/sheet are bit dark?

Tags: polarization

Why linear polarizering film/sheet are bit dark? Is there any transparent linear polarizing film/sheet available in market which absorbs glare?

Comment: Most textbooks explain the marketing sentence "polarizers reduce glare" near their section on Brewster's angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polarizers are only letting one polarization (vertical or horizontal, say) through, The rest is absorbed. Since not all light is being, transmitted the films necessarily look a bit "dark."

Comment: So there is not any single transparent linear polariser available in the market which cancels out glare, am i right?

Comment: @user248881. I have no idea about commercial products, but the physics makes it unlikely.

Comment: Even if the light is totally polarized and the polarizer is aligned to let that light pass, it will not be 100% effective as there is some absorption in the material.